# Accessing Template values in Eigen using EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

I am currently trying to adapt the Eigen API to support the following function:

matrix.similarity(similarityTransformationMatrix);

which simply does the following:

```
similarityTransformationMatrix * matrix * similarityTransformationMatrix.transpose();
```

My previous implementation only allows to take square matrices for both:

```
inline MatrixBase< Derived > similarity( const MatrixBase< Derived >& m) const {
  MatrixBase< Derived > t = m;
  t.transposeInPlace();
  return m*(*this)*t;
}
```

I need instead to be able to call this on a (square, but check for cols = rows not required) matrix, and a similarityTransformation of a different dimension. My problem is that the return matrix is not of the type of either of those, but it can be derived:

```
Matrix< double, similarityTransformation.rows(), similarityTransformation.rows()>
```

Could you give me pointers how to implement this? I didn't try implementing it as Eigen::Matrix but I'd rather stick to MatrixBase if possible, but MatrixBase didn't want to accept multiple arguments for the return type of the form

```
MatrixBase< OtherDerived::Scalar, OtherDerived::RowsAtCompileTime, OtherDerived::RowsAtCompileTime>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should notice that you cannot create object of type `MatrixBase<...>`. `MatrixBase` is just an abstract base class. In your case, `t` and the return type of `similarity` should be a `Matrix<...>` object.

Second, the template parameters of `Matrix<...>`  must be known at compile time. This means you cannot use `similarityTransformation.rows()` for that purpose but use `TYPEOF_similarityTransformation::RowsAtCompileTime`.

Third, your `similarity()` method must be templated to accept any other Eigen's expression.

Here is a proposal:

```
template<typename OtherDerived>
Matrix<Scalar, OtherDerived::RowsAtCompileTime, OtherDerived::RowsAtCompileTime>
similarity(const MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& S) const
{
  return S * ( this->derived() * S.adjoint() );
}
```

This example could be further extended to support mixing reals with complexes... (only `Scalar` has to be changed to something more complicated for type promotion..)

Comment: Hi Gaël, 
first thanks for your answer. My current implementation uses MatrixBase<Derived> as return type and it does work (though it has to be the same type as the object it's called on). What do you mean by "SHOULD" be a Matrix<...> object, are there any points I missed?
Thanks!

Comment: I've no idea how it could work. I'm pretty sure that running it under valgrind will trigger a memory error. A `MatrixBase<...>` has no attribute, this is an empty class, so it cannot hold the result of this product. I said 'should' because another possibility would be to return an expression, but that's much more tricky to get it right when products are involved.